# 404 NOT FOUND (error code : 1008) : Unknown message

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a bot in python using discord.py , i was trying delete the command when it is executed
it is working but giving me a error and the error is

> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 312, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/test_bot/add_role.py", line 25, in on_message
> msg = await message.channel.fetch_message(761275239346339871)
> File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py",
> line 956, in fetch_message
> data = await self._state.http.get_message(channel.id, id)
> File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py",
> line 243, in request
> raise NotFound(r, data)
> discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message

After giving the error also it works , but i want to know what rises the error
code :

```
msg = await message.channel.fetch_message(761275239346339871)
await msg.delete()
```

Comment: Please provide us with more code, so we might be able to deduct what the problem might be or reproduce the error for ourselves

Comment: You have this error because `fetch_message(761275239346339871)` didn't found the message you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, The message id that you inputted has already been deleted. If you want to delete the author message just do

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

if you want to delete the inputted message by `wait_for` you can do this

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
await msg.delete()
```

if `on_message`.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message = await message.channel.send(message here)
    await message.delete()
```

Comment: But i am using this in on_message() event and the message that it should delete is my bot's message

Comment: user @client.listen()